# Why wont my code build in c++ visual studio 2019, openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, build, window

My code will not build, i dont know what to try to fix it.
im trying to use c++ and openGL to make a window.
i dont have much info and dont know much but...
the build output looks like this:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: OpenGLtutorial2, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol gladLoadGLLoader referenced in function main
1>Main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol glad_glViewport
1>C:\Users\HP\source\repos\OpenGLtutorial2\x64\Debug\OpenGLtutorial2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "OpenGLtutorial2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

im not good with programming but i think the build is confusing but
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> 


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    glfwInit();

    // openGL version 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

# ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FOWARD_COPMPAT, GL_TRUE);
# endif

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL test", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) { // window not created
        std::cout << "Could not create window." << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        // send new frame to window
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

it doesent give me errors but does not build.

Comment: You need to link against the library, not just include the headers.

Comment: how? what do you mean? whee do i add them?

Comment: A quick google finds that you need to link with glfw3.lib.  https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window

Comment: i still dont know how to link something.

Comment: ***LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library*** My guess from the error message is you are attempting to link a release built library to your debug configuration.

Comment: so how do i fix that?